# if let warning in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, warnings, swift2, ios9, xcode7

Swift 2.0 is throwing warnings

> Immutable value 'a' was never used; Consider replacing it with '_' or
>   removing it

Is it fine to replace the if-let with "_" ?

```
if let a = responseString {  
    //Code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that *the code never accessed / used the constant "let a" inside the if- block*.

Probably you don't need the if-block at all if you do not need to access "let a". Maybe you used *responseString!* instead? Or do you only want to execute your code if the *responseString* is not nil (a simple if responseString != nil would do it then)?

After the if-block, the "let a" a will be marked for garbage collection or marked to be deleted after the if block during compile time (not sure about that).

Thus the compiler thinks that it is a good idea to replace the condition, as the assignment

```
let a = responseString
```

will result in false if

```
responseString == nil
```

and true in all other cases.

This condition-assignment is used in 99% of the cases to assure that e.g. the nillable variable *responseString* is not nil or even more often to automatically unwrap it on-the-fly.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax I've seen is

```
if let _ = responseString 
{
  //Code
}
```

That only runs the code inside the braces if responseString is not nil, but doesn't create a new constant.

Not sure what the compiler means by "Consider replacing it with ''". The Swift compiler's errors and warnings don't seem to make a lot of sense sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Put another way: (perhaps easier for new coders)

It is just saying that one of the variables was created but never used.
So if you used var a somewhere else it would go away.
It is also only a warning, which can be ignored if desired.

I had the same problem with my code and I just commented out the initialization of the variable since it wasn't being used currently. The solution that the compiler proposes (replacing with _) is inappropriate in cases where you want a variable of that name for future use.